# Generating Correlated Random Variable Samples with Copulas or with Choleski Decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, statistical-inference, cholesky-decomposition

Suppose I want N samples of X and Y, which are two random variables which are correlated with a certain value of correlation coefficient. They have generally non-gaussian PDF, but at the moment let's assume they are equal (for instance assume X,Y are Beta).

How to find these samples? I know two methods:

1. Suppose I can generate N normally distributed random samples with known correlation coefficient (bivariate gaussian distribution). I take these two groups of samples and apply the gaussian CDF to get uniform random variables. Then, I apply to these samples the Beta ICDFs to provide the final samples of X and Y with Beta distribution. I have been told this method inherently utilizes a **gaussian copula** as the original coupling between the input random variables was that of a gaussian bivariate distribution.
2. This way I generate again 2 groups of N normally distributed random samples, but without correlation. I turn them to Beta the same way as in 1, but now these groups are uncorrelated. Now I multiply them for **chol(Covariance Matrix)**. I get a couple of Beta random variables.

My questions are:
a) Which is the **inherent difference** between these two methods? Are them inherently equivalent? I know that copula method can be adapted to generate any type of dependence (also in absence of correlation). Is this true also for the choleski approach?

b) **Is the choleski method effective also for generated X and Y with different PDFs** (for instance one is Beta and one is Poisson?)

Comment: Are you sure that linear combinations of Beta distributed rvs are Beta distributed? Because that's what I understood you are doing in 2.